# Why do I get exception "The execution of the InstancePersistenceCommand named LoadWorkflowByInstanceKey was interrupted by an error"

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

After doing some refactoring to my WF4 service, I got this exception when calling some of the operations:

`The execution of the InstancePersistenceCommand named {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:System.Activities.Persistence/command}LoadWorkflowByInstanceKey was interrupted by an error.`

My xamlx file contains a few receive/sendreplytoreceive pairs, as shown below. The exception sometimes happens on receive2, sometimes receive3.

- receive1 (no correlation, cancreateinstance=true)
- send reply to receive (initializes content correlation on generated ID)
- receive2 (correlates on ID, cancreateinstance=false)
- send reply to receive
- receive 3 (correlates on ID, cancreateinstance=false)
- send reply to receive

After doing a lot of debugging and making sure all correlations where set up right, the exception disappeared for new instances of the workflow.

What does the exception mean, and why did it show up and why did it dissappear all of a sudden? Is it a code/xamlx issue or something with the infrastructure (AppFabric/SQL)?

I'm hosting the WF service with IIS/AppFabric, using AppFabric' SQL persistence.

Comment: I've done some more testing now. The exception comes and goes. For some wf instances all calls go through without errors, other instances fail, typically at receive3.

Comment: I'm not sure off the top of my head what's causing the problem -- however you may want to consider reading through this brief blog article so that you can get what I consider the most amazing logging available for WF (thanks @Ron Jacobs!) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/12/16/troubleshooting-workflow-services-with-diagnostic-logging.aspx

Comment: @jonsb having the same issue... but mine is persistent...

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2015127) support note this error can be the result of a race condition between the Receive and a Delay activity expiring. Is this possible in your workflow.

Comment: I doubt it. I'm testing with only a few wf instances, and not using any explicit delays. Besides, it doesn't help to retry the operation. It seems as if an instance has failed once, it will continue to fail on subsequent calls. That said, I don't fully understand Microsoft's explanation on that page...

Comment: The note says "An instance is loaded because of an expiring delay activity or an expired lock." I don't have any delay activities, but I'm not sure about locks. How and when do locks expire?

Comment: You can read the Delay expiring also as two Receive activities being activated at the same time.

Comment: Every time a workflow is loaded a logical lock is placed on the record in the instance store. That way you can share the same instance store on a server farm and workflow instances can move from one machine to another as needed. The lock is there to prevent a workflow instance from being loaded multiple times at the same time. You can also get into locking issues if you try to save a workflow after the lock has expired. The default lock time is 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, that clearified a little. I still hasn't been able to solve the problem, but I got around it by splitting my workflow into several  workflows calling each other by wcf calls. Don't know why, could have been a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda figured mine out... aparently if you point your persistance store in a SQL previous to 2012 you get the error... so all i had to do is put mine persistance store in a SQL 2012...

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem it turned out to be a mistake in my connection string when instantiating the persistence store object.

```
SqlWorkflowInstanceStore store = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(connStr);
```

I realise this an old question but fixing the connection string got rid of my error while running `store.Execute()` so I thought I'd share!